# The command "ruby" does nothing on my Mac

Tags: ruby, macos, terminal

I can't get the Ruby interpreter to run on either of my Macs (one MacBook and one MacBook Pro, both running Snow Leopard). When I run it, by typing `ruby` in Terminal, nothing happens. It just sits there. I can kill it by pressing `Ctrl+C`, but that's it. I know the Ruby process is running, since I can see it in Activity Monitor, and running `ruby --version` works fine.

I have tried the following, all to no avail:

1. I have some bash customizations, so I tried disabling them, but that didn't help.
2. I installed a new copy of Ruby 1.8.7 using MacPorts, but that one had the same problem.
3. I tried quitting and restarting the Terminal application.

Some other information that might be useful:

- I'm trying to run the version of Ruby that comes with Snow Leopard.
- I have installed Apple's developer tools.
- Other interpreters (Python, Io, etc.) work fine.

I spent a while tonight searching for this problem online, but haven't found any discussion of it. I'm at a loss for what could be causing it, so any help anybody can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Ruby command itself will just behave the way you said, either provide it with script file or use the -e option:

`ruby -e ' puts "hello world" '`

However I suspect that you want the IRB(interactive ruby). Run `irb` in your shell.

Comment: Ugh, thanks. I completely forgot that irb was a separate command.

Answer (score 10):

What are you trying to do, exactly? The `ruby` command expects input, in most cases a file that contains Ruby code that you want it to run. In that case you have to specify the name of the file:

```
> ruby my_ruby_file.rb
```

If instead you want to run the [interactive Ruby shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_Ruby_Shell), i.e. the [REPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-eval-print_loop) console that you can type Ruby code into and have it executed each time you press enter, the command you want is `irb`.